# Core data model file is not in bundle

Tags: ios, core-data, nsbundle

I rearranged the files in my program folder, grouping them into appropriate subfolders. I made sure they all show up in the compiled sources list, including the 'xcdatamodeld' file.

However, creating a managed object model is not working with the following code:

```
if (mom_ != nil) {
    return mom_;
}

self.mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

return mom_;
```

I examined `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, and specifically

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Words" ofType:@"xcdatamodeld"]
```

and

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nil ofType:@"xcdatamodeld"]
```

They both return nil. I can see that other resources are there when I check for them by name and type.

There is a folder called "Words.momd" in the app bundle file.

What might have happened and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Words" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

You want to load the *compiled* data model, vs. the xcdatamodeld file:

> A data model is a deployment resource. In addition to details of the entities and properties in the model, a model you create in Xcode contains information about the diagram—its layout, colors of elements, and so on. This latter information is not needed at runtime. The model file is compiled using the model compiler, momc, to remove the extraneous information and make runtime loading of the resource as efficient as possible.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html))

Comment: This solved the problem and is probably what I would want to use in future development. I had seen that while reading the docs, but missed the point. I still don't know why the `mergeModelFromBundles` didn't work. I have used it without problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MagicalRecords framework for it:

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

and setup your db in one line of code:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Words"];
```

Comment: This may be of use later, but it doesn't tell me anything about what is going on.